# C++ Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted

Tags: c++, pipe, named

I have a (one way) server- client communication by using "named pipe". It works so far fine, but if i close the client-programm (by pressing a specific button), i get the Error: "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted.

I know that the buffer-array from the named pipe allocates the memory, but after long searching on google i didn't find a way to solve this problem (to deallocate it). 
I have to say that i am beginner on c++.

Code:

```
char buffer[1];
DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
BOOL result = ReadFile(
        pipe,
        buffer, // the data from the pipe will be put here
        sizeof(buffer), // number of bytes allocated
        &numBytesRead, // this will store number of bytes actually read
        NULL // not using overlapped IO
        );
// object recognized, write data from inertaCube into file 
            if (buffer[0] != '0'){ // do something }

// close program by pressing left CTRL-button
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL)){
                myMeasurement.close();
                CloseHandle(pipe);
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code posted. The problem is somewhere in the code you didn't post.

Comment: 'the buffer-array from the named pipe allocates the memory' doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof(buffer)` will give you the size of `char` in your code, which is not `// number of bytes allocated`.

Comment: There seems to be one char allocated in `char buffer[1]`.

Comment: Indeed. It has just happened that the size of buffer is one (equal to sizeof(char)).